# Where to download the latest "release" version of asmack source code

Tags: android, chat, smack, asmack

I am trying to download the source code of asmack library. I found the link on github.com and some other sites. But no source code is found.
On https://code.google.com/p/asmack/downloads/list But the last commit is in 2010, it is old. 
On igniterealtime's website it is available But it is just either "Night Builds" or just a zip file containing the jar files.
But I want the complete source code of asmack. I downloaded a year back But I missed that code.

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/flowdalic/asmack. Flow is also a stackoverflow user http://stackoverflow.com/users/194894/flow

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes! I checked. But it is having compiles jars. I want to make changes in the internal library (For which the source code is used for). I want to make changes in Presence.java and its connection files, As per my requirement.

Comment: this is off topic. ask a programming related question

Answer (score 1):

aSmack's source code is almost the same with Smack, here is the aSmack project.
The aSmack project just fetches source code from Smack and apply some patches. **Note that aSmack is officially deprecated, use Smack instead.**

Smack source code:

https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack

Comment: 1 upvote, I cant because of not having 15 reputation. But only Smack code is available, asmack code is in jars on the mentioned link.

Comment: As I said above, aSmack is almost the SAME with Smack except some javax issue missing in android java core. So you can just download smack's source code instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is the repository for aSmack:
http://asmack.freakempire.de/

You can find the latest JARs and sources...

Personally, I prefer aSmack 4.0.7 for a simple connection after the headache Smack 4.2.0 caused me with SASL and the auto initialization of ServiceDiscoveryManager.class that I never got rid of without using reflection (it tries to discover the service and throws a whole lot of exceptions as it receives error IQs on many servers).